# Leaflet Popup Loop

Tags: javascript, wordpress, leaflet

I have been playing with Leaflet recently and integrated it within a WordPress custom post type. I added a field to the custom post type for a city. It is then encoded as JavaScript and sent to Mapbox for the coordinates. The coordinates then are sent to a function which displays the markers. That part works great. The problem I am having is getting the titles to loop through correctly and displaying in the popup dialog. When I look at the source code I see that both the name and city are being encoded correctly. Code is below. Thanks!

```
          // Loops through CPT and puts both city and name into array
          // TODO: Rename hometown to something more relevant
          while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

            $post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hometown', true);
            $title = get_the_title($post->ID);

            if ( !empty ( $post_meta ) || !empty ( $title ) ) {
            $hometown[] = array(
                'city' => $post_meta,
                'name' => $title
            );
        }
        endwhile;

    <script>
    var hometown = <?php echo wp_json_encode($hometown); ?>;
    var map = L.map('map').setView([40, 0], 2);

    L.mapbox.accessToken = 'myToken';

    var geocoder = L.mapbox.geocoder('mapbox.places');

    for ( var i = 0; i < hometown.length; i++ )
    {
      geocoder.query(hometown[i].city, showLoc);
    }

   L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=myToken', {
   maxZoom: 18,
attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
    '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
    'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(map);

function showLoc(err, data) {
L.marker([data.latlng[0], data.latlng[1]], 2)
    .bindPopup(hometown[0].name)
    .addTo ( map );
}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example say, we've got the following array:

```
var homes = [{
    name: 'Jane Doe',
    city: 'Denver, Colorado'
},{
    name: 'John Doe',
    city: 'Houston, Texas'
}];
```

And we're going to iterate over the array's items and query each city property from the Mapbox's geocoder service:

```
for (var i = 0; i < homes.length; i++) {
    geocoder.query(homes[i].city, callback);
}
```

That will in fact execute the following in this order:

```
geocoder.query('Denver, Colorado', callback);
geocoder.query('Houston, Texas', callback);
```

When these requests are complete it will execute the `callback` method for each query:

```
function callback (err, data) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Problem is that the requests are [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) and we have no way of being sure that they will be completed in the same order as we requested them. So inside the `callback` method we have no way of directly knowing which item the result is from:

```
function callback (err, data) {
    // Who's data is this?
}
```

Luckily the `data` object supplied by the `callback` method holds the original query in the `data.results.query` property:

```
function callback (err, data) {
    console.log(data.results.query);
}
```

That would log `['denver', 'colorado']` or `['houston', 'texas']` to your console depending on which query it's from. Now you can search your `homes` array for the city and return the name:

```
function callback (err, data) {

    // join the query array so we get the same string as we've queried
    var city = data.results.query.join(', ');

    // iterate over the homes array
    for (var i = 0; i < homes.length; i++) {

        // compare cities in lowercase (result returns in lowercase)
        if (homes[i].city.toLowerCase() === city) {

            // found match, do stuff

        }
    }
}
```

For your solution it would look something like this:

```
function callback (err, data) {
    var city = data.results.query.join(', ');
    for (var i = 0; i < homes.length; i++) {
        if (homes[i].city.toLowerCase() === city) {
             new L.Marker([data.latlng[0], data.latlng[1]])
                 .bindPopup(homes[i].name)
                 .addTo(map);
        }
    }
}
```

You can try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/73hg2L4y/ (use your own token)

Hope that helps, good luck!

Note: you will run into trouble as soon as you've got two names with the same city, so it's best you make sure that all addresses are unique.

Comment: I ran into problems when the city consists of two words (ex. New York). I modifed this line and it seems to help. `var city = data.results.query.join(' ');`   Was also considering using regex to remove any whitespaces. Now I am kinda curious if I could make some sort of counter if more than one person is from the same city and use that in the popup. Thanks! This really helps.

Comment: Just tested and indeed, i see, didn't notice. Query for 'New York, NY' returns array ['new', 'york', 'ny'] not ['new york', 'ny'] as i expected. Well just as long as you know what's going on you can adapt. I would do something like the following if i wanted to handle multiple names per city: `[{names: ['John','Peter'], city: 'Denver, Colorado'}, {names: ['Jane', 'Anne'], city: 'Houston Texas'}]` that way you'll one have one marker per city and can easily return all the names belonging to the city.

Comment: That seems like a good approach! I would probably need to get it right within the PHP array. This is just a fun project I am doing to display where staff members are from so luckily it doesn't have to be perfect.

Comment: As an update, I ended up going with Markercluster for when people are from the same place. Is working pretty good as you can see here. http://library.csueastbay.edu/scaa/about-us/scaa-staff/

You'll have to click on "By Hometown."